# How to exclude a project specific file in SonarQube

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I'm using SonarQube (6.7 at the time of this writing) to analyze my C# solution.
I'm now struggling with excluding files from duplication or full analysis.

I can exclude files like:

```
<Property Name="sonar.exclusions">**/*.Designer.cs</Property>
```

or duplications like:

```
<Property Name="sonar.cpd.exclusions">**/*.g.cs,Tests/UITest*.cs</Property>
```

As I know, the exclusion pattern is relative to the root of the project.

Now if I have the following setup:

- Project A

  - a.cs
  - b.cs
- Project B

  - a.cs
  - c.cs

And I only want to exclude the file `a.cs` from Project B but not from Project A.

Adding `a.cs` to the exclusions excludes it from both projects.

The only way I found to do this is by using an absolute path like:

> file:C:/Development/Solution/Src/Project_B/a.cs

This works but then I get a warning that using absolute filepaths (by using file:) is deprecated so this will get removed somewhen and therefore should not be used.

I already tried using relative paths like:

> ../Project_B/a.cs
>
> **OR**
>
> ./../Project_B/a.cs

But that didn't exclude any file.

Is there any non-deprecated way of removing a file only from one project?

Comment: What about <Property Name="sonar.cpd.exclusions">Src/Project_B/a.cs

Comment: As the paths are relative to the projects root, this also did not help.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? I am struggling with the same problem. :)

Comment: Unfortunately not yet.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Project B/a.cs in SonarQube. The file header will show you the path as SonarQube understands it, e.g.:

[image]

Use all or part of that path in your exclusion specification.

Comment: Hi Ann
Thanks for the answer but the problem is that this path is relative to the project. So I see `a.cs` there. If I add this, then this file is removed from Project A and from Project B but I only want it to be removed from Project B.

Comment: Your entire path string in SQ is "a.cs"?

Comment: Yes. I've rebuilt what I wrote above, here it is:
[Image](http://flauschig.ch/imgshare/img/8465410515a607a1b5e98a.png)
The path there is just `/a.cs`. For the Project_A, the `a.cs` has exactly the same path which is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *SonarQubeExclude* MSBuild property directly in your project files to exclude the whole project or individual files. See the [comments](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-msbuild/blob/master/src/SonarQube.MSBuild.Tasks/Targets/SonarQube.Integration.targets#L19) in the *SonarQube.Integration.Targets* file for more details.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. This works at least to completely exclude a project specific file from SonarQube:
`<Compile Include="a.cs">
    <SonarQubeExclude>true</SonarQubeExclude>
</Compile>`
Is there also a way to use this to only exclude a file from duplicate checks? Haven't found any hints on this.

Comment: I saw that according to https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-.net-documentation/blob/master/doc/appendix-2.md one can also set project specific settings. I tried with
`<ItemGroup>
    <SonarQubeSetting Include="sonar.cpd.exclusions">
      <Value>a.cs</Value>
    </SonarQubeSetting>
  </ItemGroup>` but that didn't exclude the file from duplicates. Although if I use `sonar.exclusions` the file gets excluded from all analysis.